# How is a meta discussion resolved?

Tags: discussion, decision

I posed a question for discussion [What is the preferred style for displaying links?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1127/70) which asked whether there was a house style or authors could markup as they pleased.

A review of the discussion can be summarised as "I prefer X" without ever addressing the over-arching question of justifying a house style. The discussion lapsed two days ago.

Now I am seeing a number of requests to endorse reformatting edits with a heavy emphasis on switching links from one style to another.

On what basis would I decide to "approve" the edit?

Comment: Comment on the answers in the link questions to say you think the answer needs more justification beyond personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

SE communities run on rough consensus.

Voting on meta works differently than voting on the regular site. A downvote on meta indicates disagreement with the post -- not necessarily anything *wrong* with the post. There's no rep associated with up/down votes on meta.

The linked question has a couple of answers indicating that links should be embedded; both of these answers have several upvotes. This seems to say that most people reading this discussion agree with the position that links should be embedded. If you think the URL should be shown inline, pitch your position, post it as an answer and let the community vote it up or down. If it attracts more upvotes, then we can see that the community thinks inline URLs are better. If it attracts downvotes, then we see that the community thinks embedded is better.

Answer (score 0):

Good question.  I think we need to agree on some standards for the site.  We have a few things in limbo right now (see my post on the geographic tags thread) and I'm wondering how we get to a final decision/consensus on such issues.  Who makes the final call?

Comment: Ultimately, the community should come to a consensus. Of course, what's decided shouldn't really go against the spirit of Q&A or Stack Exchange policy, at least not without a very strong justification for doing so. On the link question, it's clear that the norm is to use text-based links. So, in my opinion, the community should have a good strong argument for not using the markup. Also, this will be easier once the SE team appoints moderators to help the community work through such issues.

Comment: @jmort This particular issue arose because it is **not** " clear that the norm is to use text-based links". Certainly "the community should come to a census" but I see no indication that there is a mechanism for that to occur.

Comment: One tool moderators will have is the ability to put special [meta-tag:status-completed] tags on posts, which can help indicate the issue has been resolved and the process implemented. However, some discussions are just plain ongoing too. :)